# How to add space between item row?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have this design

[image]

This is what I have now

```
 export default function Minter({
  ...
}) {
 
  const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      Choose file
    </div>
  );

  const uploadView = (
    <div style={{ padding: 50 }}>
      <p className="uppercase text-gray-400 mb-6 text-center">
        PNG, GIF, WEBP, MP4 or MP3. Max 100mb.
      </p>
      <Upload
        name="avatar"
        accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif"
        listType="picture-card"
        className="avatar-uploader"
        showUploadList={false}
        action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
        beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
      >
        {uploadButton}
      </Upload>
    </div>
  );

  const preview = previewURL ? <img src={previewURL} style={{ maxWidth: "800px" }} /> : <div />

  const nameField = (
    <Input
      style={{
        border: 0,

      }}
      placeholder="Enter a name" onChange={e => {
        setName(e.target.value);
      }} />
  );

  const descriptionField = (
    <Input.TextArea
      placeholder="Enter a description" onChange={e => {
        setDescription(e.target.value);
      }} />
  );


  const priceField = (
    <Input.TextArea placeholder="Enter a price" onChange={e => {
      setPrice(e.target.value);
    }} />
  );


  const mintButton = (
    <Button type="primary" disabled={!mintEnabled} onClick={startMinting}>
      {minting ? <LoadingOutlined /> : "Mint!"}
    </Button>
  )

  const minterForm = (
    <body>
      <div style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
        display: "flex", flexDirection: "column",
      }}>
        <div style={{justifyContent:'space-between',display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <div style={{
            borderStyle: 'dotted',
            borderRadius: 1,
          }}>
            {file == null && uploadView}
            {preview}
          </div>
          <div>
            <div> Name</div>
            {nameField}
            <p>Description</p>
            {descriptionField}
            <p>Price</p>
            {priceField}
            {mintButton}
            {status}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </body>
  );
  return minterForm;
}
```

1. How to add space in middle?
2. How to align name,description,price to left?
3. I would like to shorten the height of the "Choose file", make it look exactly like the above image.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer some of these questions as there's no reproducible code link (CodeSandbox, etc).

The outer flexbox is likely causing some issues as it's probably not letting the children breathe - for these two components you should only need one parent flex with both `justify-content: center` and `align-items: center`

1. `gap` css property for flex/grid should be your friend here. If adding a `gap` on the second flex does nothing, see above or add a minWidth.
2. This is likely due to other styles interfering. Either add an explicit `text-align: left`, or use the Inspect feature of your browser to see what's happening.
3. Add a `maxHeight` to the div, or look into what styles are being applied by the `avatar-uploader` class.

I'd look into the Material UI library, as the `TextField` component has similar styling to the reference image.